# How much state can I save in session variables for a web app?

Tags: api, web-applications, rest, rpc

I'm coding up a REST/RPC API for a web app that I'm creating. From what I've learned it seems like one of the core ideas behind REST is to not maintain any state. That said I find myself doing things like marking a session as authenticated on the server side of things and this feels like saving state. How far should I take this practice? Where should I draw the line? There are other things that would be really convenient to save as part of the session's variables but I'm wondering how do I know when I shouldn't or shouldn't do this.

I hope this is the right venue to ask this question. I debated on whether or not to post it in programmers but this just felt more appropriate.

**UPDATE:**

I'm told that using a ticketing system is better than using session variables to maintain things like auth information. Could someone include and answer that has a very highly description of how such a ticketing system would work?

Comment: Have you considered HTTP BASIC authentication?

Comment: Yes, but I heard security for it is atrocious. Namely the credentials are passed in plain text.

Comment: It's not less safe than a plain HTML form with a session. You'll see all request parameters and cookies plain vanilla as well. Just use HTTPS if you want to encrypt the transport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - REST calls are ideally stateless, and storing something in a session variable, and using that for the REST call, is anathema. You can't, for instance, guarantee that a RESTful client can even send the cookie information necessary for the session variables.

If you need authentication, then you should have REST calls that return something like a ticket, then the REST caller would send that ticket as part of another call.

**UPDATE**
For a ticketing system, you generally want to use the same auth or similar auth system. For instance, if you require a user name and password, you might want the ticket request to POST that. A ticket is a GUID that is passed on subsequent calls. The ticket on the server can be stored in session, or in a DB (I typically have a TICKETS table, with things like expiration dates).

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://site.com?action=auth&user=matt&password=pass');
// parse $result XML for ticket or auth error
// subsequent calls...
$result = file_get_contents('http://site.com?action=getSomething&ticket=" . $ticket);
```

QuickBase works this way - you send an API_Auth action with a username, password and api app token, and get a ticket in return. Then you pass your api app token and the ticket on subsequent calls - both GET requests and POST sends.

Comment: So as far as I can tell, saving auth state in session variables is fairly standard practice. I'm I wrong in saying that? Or are the people that are doing that not conforming to REST?

Comment: Absolutely true - saving auth state in session is standard practice. And also true, people doing that for REST calls are not conforming. In many instances, the purpose for REST is to make server-side APIs and Javascript Ajax APIs easy to use. However, neither of those types of calls are guaranteed to be able to handle the needs of a server storing auth and other session information. Use a ticketing system instead.

Comment: With GET requests, isn't this approach vulnerable then to MitM attacks? If someone just sniffs the url that you're sending, they'll be able to see your ticked and impersonate you.

Comment: Both GET and POSTs are vulnerable to sniffing. I generally use a POST for something like this, it was just easier to show in a GET request. I built a Yammer-like website for Intuit, using Laconica as a base, but the original auth was GET like this. I made it SSL, POST, and ticket based to better secure it. An SSL GET is just as secure as an SSL POST - both are encrypted using the public site key. Only the IP address retrieved from the domain server is "in the clear".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4374/discussion-between-kurtis-nusbaum-and-matt-h)