# Does a ticketing system break my REST paradigm?

Tags: web-applications, authentication, rest, rpc, restful-authentication

So in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7815293/527288) I asked about whats the most RESTful way to do something like authentication. The response was to create a ticketing system where a post was done, and a ticket was issued. Then all further requests would send along this ticket. My question is, how do I send along this ticked with each request in a RESTful manner? Would GETs look something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/resource?ticket=ticketnumber
```

And isn't this starting to get RPCish now that I'm including parameters?

Comment: More like `http://www.mysite.com/tickets` (list of tickets) or `http://www.mysite.com/tickets/123` (ticket 123)

Comment: No, I mean that the request for resource has to include the ticket

Comment: Generally speaking simplicity is a good thing. But pure REST assumes the world in much simpler than it really is. For 95% of problems this does not matter as REST is good enough. But for the other 5% its simply too naive. Web Services on the other hand can deal with almost any situation regarding authorization, security, and state, but the price of this is an almost absurd degree of complication. You have a situation that can be handled easily with REST plus a couple of parameters -- just do it and don't worry about "purity".

Comment: @JamesAnderson That's exactly the kind of stuff I wanna hear. Why not put it in an answer so I van vote it up?

Comment: @Kurtis -- its more of an opinion than an answer -- so I think its more appropriate as a comment. Plus I've got enough rep for the month :-}

Comment: There's absolutely nothing unrestful about including parameters in a URI. The state of your resources should be addressable by URI. That's it. There's nothing wrong with manipulating the representation of a resource based on other information (Accept header, Accept-Language header, cookies, etc.), but the underlying state of the resource should depend only on the URI. If the URI includes parameters, fine. Each combination of parameters addresses a different resource. I would prefer the use of headers for sending auth information, unless the resource itself changes based on that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use standard HTTP authentication methods instead of inventing your own? If they're not sufficient or appropriate, add your credentials or ticketing info to a custom header rather than polluting the URI with it.

Your URIs should identify your resources, no more, no less. Adding meta or contextual information to the URI pollutes them and will make your system more difficult to evolve, because your authentication mechanism will be directly and permanently coupled to your resources. Instead, move your authentication mechanism into an HTTP header, where it belongs.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of adding custom data to the HTTP header?

Comment: I can, but that warrants a separate question rather than a comment. Others can find the answer then (and contribute their code, too).